# How do I prevent node.js from waiting for keyboard input?

Tags: node.js

I was trying to write a node.js script that only takes input from stdin if it's piped (as opposed to wait input from keyboard). Therefore I need to determine whether the `stdin` piped in is `null`.

First I tried using the `readable` event:

```
var s = process.stdin;
s.on('readable', function () {
    console.log('Event "readable" is fired!');
    var chunk = s.read();
    console.log(chunk);
    if (chunk===null) s.pause();
});
```

And the result is as expected:

```
$ node test.js
Event "readable" is fired!
null
$
```

Then I tried to do the same thing using `data` event, because I like to use flowing mode:

```
var s = process.stdin;
s.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('Event "data" is fired!');
    console.log(chunk);
    if (chunk===null) s.pause();
});
```

but this time it waited for keyboard input before the null check, and stucked there. I was wondering why it does that? Does that mean in order to do a null check, I need to `pause` it first, and wait `readable` to be fired, do the null check, and then `resume` the stream, just to prevent node.js from waiting keyboard input? This seems awkward to me. Is there a way to avoid using `readable` event?

Comment: You don't need to do `s.pause();` on 'readable'. What that's actually doing is implicitly converting the stdin stream from streams2 mode ('readable' event and .read()) to streams1 mode ('data' events, .pause(), .resume(), etc). Also when using .read(), you should do that in a loop until null is received, to get all of the buffered input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [tty.isatty()](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_tty_isatty_fd) from the node core library. That function will return `false` if stdin is a pipe.